# How long will it take to get from Los Angeles Metro's 7th St./Metro Center to Hollywood and Highland via Metro Red?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, los-angeles

I plan to take Metro's Red Line subway in Los Angeles to get from Metro's 7th St./Metro Center station to Hollywood and Highland station on a Friday at around 1:00-1:30pm, and would like to know how long this journey will take. I am, however, unable to find the total journey time on Google Maps or on Metro's trip planner, which I find to be quite strange, as they normally do have this kind of data.

I've checked the Red Line's schedule for the westbound train and there is one that departs from 7th St./Metro Center station at around this time period.

Comment: @anomuse - if only it showed me this when I used it

Comment: Also useful is the [nextbus.com feed for the stop](https://www.nextbus.com/#!/lametro-rail/802/802_1_var0/80211_1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find complete Metro timetables at https://www.metro.net/riding/maps/.  The [current Red Line PDF timetable](https://media.metro.net/documents/b4f1f223-c6b4-4b6e-bd18-648dbca1e7e9.pdf) shows a travel time of 16 minutes from 7th St/Metro Center to Hollywood/Highland at all times of the day (e.g. departure 1:28, arrival 1:44).  There is a disclaimer that times are approximate.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, it should take about 25-30 minutes from the time you board. Between 7th/Metro Center to Hollywood and Highland, there are eight stops.